# I'm trying to parse an XML in PL/SQL. I am unable to retrieve the attribute values from a tag, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: plsql, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, plsqldeveloper

The following XML won't parse. Please find the exact code I'm using -

```
DECLARE
  x XMLType := XMLType(
    '<ns0:CreateSODSOrder xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.dell.com/services/isp/OrderHistory/3.5" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" MessageType="CREATE">
  <ns0:CreateOrder>
    <ns0:SalesOrder ORDER_NUM="302199286" DPID="GB2003-2120-85049" PO_NUM="test" ORDER_BUID="202" DPS_NUM="" CHANNEL="ENTP" SUB_CHANNEL="GB_IC1A" ORDER_TYPE="GB ENT Order" REBOOKED_ORDER_NUM="" SALES_REP_NAME="SANJANA_D_C" ORIGINAL_ORDER_REF_NUM="" AMF_ORDER_NUM="" IR_NUM="GB2003-2120-85049" CCN="GB_IC1A" CUSTOMER_NUM="GB90117414" CUSTOMER_BUID="202" ORDER_DATE="2019-09-30T07:59:32" COUNTRY_NUM="GB" CCN_DESC="GB Indirect Certified  Tier 1A"/>
  </ns0:CreateOrder>
</ns0:CreateSODSOrder>');
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(column_value,'Sales/@ORDER_NAME') as name
         -- ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/row/Address/State/text()') as state
          --,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/row/Address/City/text()') as city
    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/CreateSODSOrder/CreateOrder/SalesOrder')))
    ) LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(r.name);
  END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('out');
END;
```

When I use ns0: with the CreateSODSOrder/CreateOrder/SalesOrder, it throws an XML parsing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the XML parse error because namespace definition is missing.
Following code will solve the namespace problem but it's hard to get values without knowing what you intend

```sql
DECLARE
  x XMLType := XMLType(
    '<ns0:CreateSODSOrder xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.dell.com/services/isp/OrderHistory/3.5" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" MessageType="CREATE">
  <ns0:CreateOrder>
    <ns0:SalesOrder ORDER_NUM="302199286" DPID="GB2003-2120-85049" PO_NUM="test" ORDER_BUID="202" DPS_NUM="" CHANNEL="ENTP" SUB_CHANNEL="GB_IC1A" ORDER_TYPE="GB ENT Order" REBOOKED_ORDER_NUM="" SALES_REP_NAME="SANJANA_D_C" ORIGINAL_ORDER_REF_NUM="" AMF_ORDER_NUM="" IR_NUM="GB2003-2120-85049" CCN="GB_IC1A" CUSTOMER_NUM="GB90117414" CUSTOMER_BUID="202" ORDER_DATE="2019-09-30T07:59:32" COUNTRY_NUM="GB" CCN_DESC="GB Indirect Certified  Tier 1A"/>
  </ns0:CreateOrder>
</ns0:CreateSODSOrder>');
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (
    SELECT ExtractValue(column_value,'Sales/@ORDER_NAME') as name
         -- ,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/row/Address/State/text()') as state
          --,ExtractValue(Value(p),'/row/Address/City/text()') as city
    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/ns0:CreateSODSOrder/ns0:CreateOrder/ns0:SalesOrder', 'xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.dell.com/services/isp/OrderHistory/3.5"' )))
    ) LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(r.name);
  END LOOP;
    dbms_output.put_line('out');
END;
```

It's a good idea to use `XMLTABLE` since `ExtractValue` is bit old fashioned and deprecated.

Example code to get attributes with `XMLTABLE` is added below.

```sql
DECLARE
CURSOR get_data IS
SELECT * 
FROM XMLTABLE(xmlnamespaces('http://schemas.dell.com/services/isp/OrderHistory/3.5' as "ns0", 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' as "soap-env" ),'ns0:CreateSODSOrder/ns0:CreateOrder/ns0:SalesOrder'
   passing xmltype('<ns0:CreateSODSOrder xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.dell.com/services/isp/OrderHistory/3.5" xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" MessageType="CREATE">
  <ns0:CreateOrder>
    <ns0:SalesOrder ORDER_NUM="302199286" DPID="GB2003-2120-85049" PO_NUM="test" ORDER_BUID="202" DPS_NUM="" CHANNEL="ENTP" SUB_CHANNEL="GB_IC1A" ORDER_TYPE="GB ENT Order" REBOOKED_ORDER_NUM="" SALES_REP_NAME="SANJANA_D_C" ORIGINAL_ORDER_REF_NUM="" AMF_ORDER_NUM="" IR_NUM="GB2003-2120-85049" CCN="GB_IC1A" CUSTOMER_NUM="GB90117414" CUSTOMER_BUID="202" ORDER_DATE="2019-09-30T07:59:32" COUNTRY_NUM="GB" CCN_DESC="GB Indirect Certified  Tier 1A"/>
  </ns0:CreateOrder>
</ns0:CreateSODSOrder>')
           COLUMNS 
           ORDER_NUM      VARCHAR2(30)    PATH '@ORDER_NUM',
           DPID           VARCHAR2(30)    PATH '@DPID');
BEGIN  
FOR rec_ IN get_data LOOP
  dbms_output.put_line(rec_.ORDER_NUM);
  dbms_output.put_line(rec_.DPID);
  END LOOP;
END;
```